# When is the frame size of a UIButton finally set

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I made a custom subclass of `UIButton` so I can add an extra label. When this button is in an `UIStackView`, the extra label is not being sized properly. I tried programmatically adding constraints to parent button. This worked but I had pages of broken constraint warnings (slight exaggeration). If I knew when the button has been assigned a final size, I can set the added labels frame.

When is the size of a `UIButton` known after all the auto layout stuff is done?

Comment: Have you check the StackView fill property value?

Comment: The frame of a button should be known and can be used when layoutSubviews() is called, this can be overridden in your custom class

Comment: This is set when you add the button is aded to the `UIView`. Or in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks Ben, layoutSubviews did it.

Comment: Ben, correct - I use that, or viewWillLayoutSubviews in the superview. @Jimmy, that's very bad advice - when Auto layout is involved, I'd recommend never using viewDidLoad, as many (all?) times a view instantiated in code will have no frame yet.

Comment: @S'rCat, please note that viewWillLayoutSubviews and viewDidLayoutSubviews may be called multiple times before the view appears and also sometimes after the view has appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments above, the frame of a button should be known and can be used when layoutSubviews() is called, this can be overridden in your custom class

Answer (score 0):

**viewDidLayoutSubViews** is the method which finish last. While assigning auto layout constraints it gives you proper **Rect** information. You can use this to set constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: put  "print("frame is: ", button.frame," in method name")" in the following methods.

viewDidLoad

viewDidLayoutSubviews

viewWillLayoutSubviews

viewWillAppear

viewDidAppear

You'll notice that the actual final frame of the button doesn't happen until the final call of viewDidLayoutSubviews and then viewDidAppear, and that viewDidLayoutSubviews is called a number of times before that, which is especially annoying when you're trying to resize the font on this label according to the size of the button's title label.

If the stack view is messing with your sizing, drag a UIView into the stack view and put the button in it, then you can constrain the button to that view.